# What is happening in this situation?

Tags: capacitor

I have been experimenting with capacitors on a breadboard with a multimeter. A circuit with a diode and a 6v battery (and nothing else) gave the following readings on a multimeter:

```
Voltage: -4.81v
```

I replaced the diode with a capacitor, and got the following readings:

```
Voltage: starts at -6v and steadily decreases to -0.1v
```

I understand that a capacitor stores energy in its electric field and releases it when the current is low, but what are the properties of a circuit that contains a capacitor? What laws, etc. cause the voltage to trickle down and the resistance to be at that value?

*Note: I literally just picked out a diode and a capacitor from a big pile of mixed components. I do not know how many farads/voltage drop they have.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg5aZA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Use the circuit editor to clarify what kind of thing you're looking at, and where you measure. We can't read your mind, so this question remains unclear. Also, the unit of voltage is Volt, and abbreviated with a capital "V", not a small "v".

Comment: We work with circuit diagrams and just because you get a resistance reading it doesn't necessarily mean you are measuring a resistance

Comment: Creating a circuit diagram at the moment

Comment: m.i.c..k.e.y why?

Comment: sorry didn't know there was a circuit editor

Comment: If you replace **what you think is a voltmeter** with what it actually is - **a current meter with a high series resistance** the circuit should become clearer. i.e. you are charging a capacitor with a high value resistor (long time constant) and monitoring the slow decay of current as it charges.

Comment: Attempting to meaure resistance in a circuit with voltage applied will give totally meaningless results, as an Ohmmeter applies a voltage, and uses the resulting current (or applies a current and uses the resulting voltage) to determine the resistance between its leads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not provide a circuit schematic diagram or component values we have to guess what you are measuring. However you are describing the classic observations of the capacitor charging.

"Resistance" readings from a simple DMM performed on a capacitor really has no useful meaning.  There are too many variables to even know what the readings mean.

Consider getting one of those $10-15 "LCD Transistor Tester meter Diode Triode Capacitance LCR ESR Meter" gadgets available from dozens of vendors on Ebay. They are quite amazing value for very low cost and can identify, measure and analyze mystery components, and also help you understand different components. Highly recommended.

The voltage across the capacitor Asymptotically approaches the charging voltage. Here is an example of the classic capacitor charging curve:

[image: Capacitor charging curve]

Comment: Does the voltage stay at that level or does it fluctuate? Am I observing it for long enough?

Comment: The voltage level Asymptotically approaches the charging voltage. I have edited my response to include the classic curve.